# IOS Configure Terminal equiv in C3700 Software

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, access-point

I'm so used to using `conf t` to get into configuration mode, but it doesn't work in "Cisco IOS Software, C3700 Software (AP3G2-RCVK9W8-M), Version 15.3(3)JA3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)"

What's the equivalent command to get into the configuration mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightweight Wireless Access Points (LWAP) such as the C3700 are configured by the controller, but if you want to access the configuration mode on the LWAP you must first type ***debug capwap console cli***. Without this, an LWAP will not accept the `conf t` command. If you want to convert it to autonomous, follow this link [lightweight-to-autonomous-conversion](http://mrncciew.com/2012/10/20/lightweight-to-autonomous-conversion/).